# Separate elements background opacity from it's content opacity

Tags: html, css

I wanna get this:
[The Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXBmf.jpg) &
[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnden.jpg)
The thing is that my code goes like this:

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>whiterose</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background: #5d5e62;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 110%;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}
header h1 {
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding: 0.5% 0;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    display: inline;
}
header nav {
    display: inline;
    overflow: auto;
}
header nav ul {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 55%;
}
header nav ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 0.3%;
    display: inline;
}
header nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

So why even if I append the  and  elements to the parent element (header) they still have the opacity property applied?

Comment: You want your text to be of 0.7 opacity. Is that correct?

Comment: according to the target image , the text is in full opacity and the background is of opacity 0.7

Comment: i want the header to have opacity e.g. "0.7" but the text to still opacity 1.0.

Comment: So just give the opacity to the header's background color, and not to it's content

Comment: @Esteban, Please mark the correct answer as the accepted one so future users can also find it useful...

Answer (score 4):

You need to give the opacity to the header's background, and not to it's content:

```
header {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Check the demo in the snippet:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
<div>Your Text Goes Here</div>
```

Comment: sorry sir but it still, I just want the background to have transparency (opacity), but the text inside (Even if I give it the property of opacity: initial), stills inherits the opacity from the background, just like if the background was foward the text and not backwards!

Comment: @Esteban Check the demo... It works just like you asked... the red div has a semi-transparent background, and a solid text color.

Comment: Then accepting the answer is the right way to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `rgba` value for the `background-color` property.
I've created a jsfiddle with this.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa9rkxzf/)

You can play around with the opacity value to suit your needs

Answer (score 1):

If you put opacity of parent element, it's child elements will automatically get the same opacity. If you try to be smart and define opacity of child element, believe me it won't work.

So, solution here is very simple. You want your header color to be #5d5e62 with opacity 0.7. Just convert this hex value in rgb and define background color as

```
background: rgba(93,94,98,0.7);
```

That way all child elements will have opacity 1 while background color will be of opacity 0.7.

I hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Thaks Vineet but It doesn't work, I tried taking the h1 out of the header and it stills, the "opacity" property seems to be "omnipotent".

Comment: header {
    background:rgba(93,94,98,0.7);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 110%;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
} change header css by this